# Можно ли автоматически подставить формулу из предыдущей ячейки в новую в excel

Tags: python, excel

Имеется таблица, в которой в каждом столбце представлены значения, полученные с помощью формул.

Столбцов много и для каждого прописывать формулу будет затратно (но возможно, это единственный вариант).

Можно ли как-то автоматизировать заполнение новых полей соответствующими формулами?

Пока что вижу только такое решение (пример для одного столбца):

1. получение формулы из предыдущей ячейки

```
cell = wc.cell(row=293, column=2)
formula = cell.value

>>> '=(List1!B353/List1!B352*100)/List1!C353*100'
```

2. нахождение в этой формуле чисел, представляющие собой номера ячеек

```
import re

pattern = r'([A-Z][0-9]+)'
values = re.findall(pattern, formula)
for v in values:
    print(v)

>>> B353
>>> B352
>>> C353
```

3. затем отделить цифры от букв и увеличить каждое значение на 1 и заменить прошлое значение в формуле на новое

```
for v in values:
    new = v[0]+int(v[1:])+1
    formula = formula.replace(v, new)
print(formula)

>>> '=(List1!B354/List1!B353*100)/List1!C354*100'
```

4. применить новую формулу к следующей ячейке

```
cell = wc.cell(row=294, column=2)
cell.value = formula
```

Comment: посмотрите тут, может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931751/copy-formula-from-one-cell-to-another-using-openpyxl

Comment: да, благодарю. все работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример для одного столбца

```
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator

prev_cell = wc.cell(row=293, column=2)
formula = prev_cell.value
cell = wc.cell(row=294, column=2)
cell.value = Translator(formula, f"{prev_cell.column_letter}293").translate_formula(f"{prev_cell.column_letter}294")

print(formula)
print(cell.value)

>>> =(List1!B354/List1!B353*100)/List1!C354*100
>>> =(List1!B355/List1!B354*100)/List1!C355*100
```